# Why do I get an error on Quotes.Id in my SOQL query

Tags: apex, soql, query, nested

I have the following query where when I remove the where part it works fine. When I add the WHERE part I get an error on Quotes.Id `SELECT Name, StageName, CloseDate , Amount, (SELECT Id FROM Quotes) FROM Opportunity WHERE Quotes.Id='0Q00E0000004PEESA2' ORDER by Name`

Comment: What do you want to achieve from above query?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't filter a child value like that directly, but you can use a subquery:

```
WHERE Id IN (SELECT OpportunityId FROM Quote WHERE Id = '0Q00E0000004PEESA2')
```